# Can very deeply nesting React routing be simplified by duplicating routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I'm using React router v4. I'm building a basic "profile" feature.

The main structure is the following one :
I got a profile list table ( /catalog-view/profils )
Inside this same page, the user can create a profile by clicking a button.

So the user clicks on that button, the routing is changing for /catalog-view/profils/create.
You ended with the table list AND the "create profil" component on the same page.

AND inside that component, you can navigate between two URLs ( /catalog-view/profils/create which is the base one and /catalog-view/profils/create/profileId)

```
const ProfilsSection = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ProfileCreationPanel {...props} /> <---- THAT ONE IS THE COMPONENT THAT LEADS TO CREATE A PROFIL
            <DisponibilitiesSectionContainer />
            <ProfilsTableSectionContainer />
        </Fragment>
    )
};

<---THAT COMPONENT IS RESPONSIBLE FOR DISPLAYING THE CONTENT COMPONENT FOR BOTH ROUTE
const ProfileCreationPanel = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.DELIVERY]}
                path={profileCreationPath.path.creation}
                render={props => <Content {...props} />}
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.DELIVERY]}
                path={profileCreationPath.path.editClients}
                render={props => <Content {...props} />}
            />
        </Fragment>
    )
};

<---THAT ONE IS WRAPPED IN A SWITCH TO DISPLAY THE RIGHT CONTENT ACCORDING TO THE EXACT PATH
const ProfilesContent = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.DELIVERY]}
                path={profileCreationPath.path.creation}
                render={props => <ProfileInformationsContainer {...props} />}
            />
            <ProtectedRoute
                exact
                AUTHORIZED_ROLES={[USER_ROLES.DELIVERY]}
                path={profileCreationPath.path.editClients}
                render={props => "second component"}
            />
        </Switch>
    )
};

export default ProfilesContent;
```

And finally those are my routes

```
export const profileCreationPath = {
    path: {
        creation: `${catalogRoutes.deliveryProfils.path}/creation`,
        editClients: `${catalogRoutes.deliveryProfils.path}/creation/:profileId`
    },
    buildPath: ({ isEditingClients, profileId }) =>
        !isEditingClients ? profileCreationPath.path.creation
            : toProfileCreationEditingClientsPath({ profileId })
}

export const toProfileCreationEditingClientsPath = pathToRegexp.compile(profileCreationPath.path.editClients);
```

This is a working case but I feel there is a better way to do so.
Everything looks quite messy and I wonder if Route duplication to render the same content component according to different routes is the right thing to do